# How to recreate win7 phone sliding effect in wpf app

Tags: wpf, effects, transition

I have been playing around with the window phone emulator and am curious how i can replicate the transitions in my wpf app.  I have looked a several different ways to create transitions, however I can't seem to find anything that mimics their sliding.  I think i might be looking at it wrong but most of the examples i have seen use multiple usercontrols. However it appears on their emulator they are using one... any ideas on how the are doing this?  (you can find the effect i'm trying to create on the settings page... sliding between system and application)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257509/WPF-Metro-A-Win8-Start-screen-Clone This should give you some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lex Li suggested here is a good article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257509/WPF-Metro-A-Win8-Start-screen-Clone

I also found this that is a good as well
http://wpfspark.codeplex.com/